# Linq to read xml into classes with where clause filtering

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have xml in this format. I am trying to load this data into classes, based on some selective clauses

```
<Data

<CST>

<CA Type="type" Idea="Idea">
  <Var Name="Test" Value="some value" />
</CA>


<CA Type="type2" Idea="Idea2">
  <Var Name="Test2" Value="some value" />
</CA>


 <CA Type="type3" Idea="Idea3">
    <Var Name="Test" Value="some value" />
 </CA>

 </CST>

 </Data>
```

My code in linq to read xml is like this.

```
        IEnumerable<CA> casValues = (from s in doc.Root.Element("CST").Elements("CA")
                                 select new CA
                                 {
                                     Type = s.Attribute("Type").Value,
                                     Idea = s.Attribute("Idea").Value,
                                     Variable = (from k in s.Elements("Var")
                                                 select new Variable
                                                 {
                                                     Name = k.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                                     Value = k.Attribute("Value").Value
                                                 }).FirstOrDefault()
                                 });
```

This returns all the CA and their var values loaded properly. However when I try to filter it further, because I am only interested in values with var name="test", I get an empty collection with error

```
"{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}"
```

I am using simple filtering like this.

```
 IEnumerable<CA> tt = casValues.Where(x => x.Variable.Name == "Test");
```

I am assuming this is because Variable is a class and I cannot directly use the value. The same works when I load each element with foreach checking for my condition. What I am missing with above code?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: The posted XML sample doesn't throw that exception. Please post minimal XML sample that demonstrate the problem, so that we can be sure what really need to be fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will throw such exception in some cases, among them, in case when `Type` or `Idea` attribute not found in the current `<CA>` node, or when `<Var>` child node is not found.

One possible way to avoid exception in above mentioned occasions, instead of accessing the `Value` property directly, try to cast `XAttribute` or `XElement` to the expected type* :

```
var casValues = (from s in doc.Root.Element("CST").Elements("CA")
                 select new CA
                            {
                                Type = (string)s.Attribute("Type"),
                                Idea = (string)s.Attribute("Idea"),
                                Variable = (from k in s.Elements("Var")
                                            select new Variable
                                                       {
                                                           Name = (string)k.Attribute("Name"),
                                                           Value = (string)k.Attribute("Value")
                                                       }).FirstOrDefault()
                            });
```

<sub>*</sub>) List of available types for explicit conversion : [XElement Explicit Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [XAttribute Explicit Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed that some of the values do not have Var assigned. I just added a null check in where clause and that resolved it.